# Performance TestCase Interface in Android

Tags: android, performance, testing

Has anybody implemented the ***PerformanceTestCase*** provided by *android* and got some results...If you have done it please provide some *source code*,it will be really helpful...

Here is the android link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/PerformanceTestCase.html

I have used the ***traceview*** tool but I need results like *CPU cycles* used,*memory* used by the app either in real-time or after its execution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a wrapper class for performance test case in android source code called as ***performance test base***..you can use that class to get performance parameters...Also see the ***performance collector*** and ***performance collector test*** class for more information..